# Populate TableView using ArrayList - JavaFx

Tags: java, arraylist, javafx, tableview, observablelist

I'm trying to populate a TableView with an arrayList. I have an array list called 'personArray' that is populated in a class called Person. This array contains the elements type, name, gender, age, ethnicity, dob, address, statement, harm and defence. Using breakpoints I can see that the array has been correctly populated before the table is created. The array list is then converted in an observable list 'people'.

The following code then creates the table. The code should take the values from the observable list 'people' and populate the table, but it does not. The table remains blank. I have tried many different solutions and nothing has worked.

```
    TableView<Person> peopleTable = new TableView<Person>();
    ObservableList<Person> people = FXCollections.observableArrayList(personArray);

    TableColumn<Person, String> typeCol = new TableColumn<Person, String>("Type");
    typeCol.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("type")
        );

    TableColumn<Person, String> nameCol = new  TableColumn<Person, String>("Name");
    nameCol.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("name"));

    TableColumn<Person, String> genderCol = new  TableColumn<Person, String>("Gender");
    genderCol.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("gender")
        );

    TableColumn<Person, String> ageCol = new  TableColumn<Person, String>("Age");
    ageCol.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("age")
        );

    TableColumn<Person, String> ethnicityCol = new TableColumn<Person, String>("Ethnicity");
    ethnicityCol.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("ethnicity")
        );

    TableColumn<Person, String> dobCol = new  TableColumn<Person, String>("Date of Birth");
    dobCol.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("dob")
        );

    TableColumn<Person, String> addressCol = new  TableColumn<Person, String>("Address");
    addressCol.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("address")
        );

    TableColumn<Person, String> statementCol = new  TableColumn<Person, String>("Statement");
    statementCol.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("statement")
        );

    TableColumn<Person, String> harmCol = new  TableColumn<Person, String>("Harm");
    harmCol.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("harm")
        );

    TableColumn<Person, String> defenceCol = new TableColumn<Person, String>("Defence");
    defenceCol.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("defence")
        );


    peopleTable.getColumns().addAll(typeCol, nameCol, genderCol, ageCol, ethnicityCol, dobCol, addressCol,
            statementCol, harmCol, defenceCol);

    peopleTable.setItems(people);
```

I'm new to Java so I'm not sure what to do?

EDIT:

This is my Person class (not including the create method that creates a new person and places it in personArray, as this works as it should).

```
public class Person {

protected static ArrayList<Person> personArray = new ArrayList<Person>();

protected enum personType {
    Suspect("Suspect"), Victim("Victim"), Witness("Witness");

    private String typeName;

    personType(String typeName) {
       this.typeName = typeName;
    }

   public String toString() {
    return this.typeName;
   }
}

protected enum genderType {
    Male("Male"), Female("Female");

    private String genderName;

    genderType(String genderName) {
       this.genderName = genderName;
    }

   public String toString() {
    return this.genderName;
   }
}

protected enum ethnicityType {
    White("White"), Black("Black"), Asian("Asian"), Indian("Indian");

    private String ethnicityName;

    ethnicityType(String ethnicityName) {
       this.ethnicityName = ethnicityName;
    }

   public String toString() {
    return this.ethnicityName;
   }
}

protected personType type;
protected String name;
protected genderType gender;
protected int age;
protected ethnicityType ethnicity;
protected LocalDate dob;
protected String address;
protected String statement;
protected String harm;
protected String defence;

protected Person(personType getType, String getName, genderType getGender, int getAge,
        ethnicityType getEthnicity, LocalDate getDob, String getAddress, String getStatement, String getHarm, String getDefence) {

    type = getType;
    name = getName;
    age = getAge;
    gender = getGender;
    ethnicity = getEthnicity;
    dob = getDob;
    address = getAddress;
    statement = getStatement;
    harm = getHarm;
    defence = getDefence;
}
}
```

Is this correct? Because it still does not work

Comment: Looks fine to me. Just make sure the strings like `firstName` used in `PropertyValueFactory` like `new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("firstName")` matches the variable name of the Person POJO class. If you still have questions, post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for further debugging.

Comment: By "variable name" you really mean "property name". I.e. the field can be called anything; what matters are the names of the methods.

Comment: ^^ My mistake. Yeah, I meant the property name, or setters & getters in normal pojo's

Comment: You are missing the setters and getters for each of the Person attributes. The `PropertyValueFactory` binds the `String passed to it with their setters and getters`. Add them in the POJO class and get back in case of troubles.

Comment: You also have the wrong types for some of the columns (`typeCol`, `ethnicityCol`, `genderCol`, and `dobCol`).